# Image Showing as junk characters in the browser

Tags: php, html, mime-types

Can anyone please let me know why, when I am trying to access the image URL through the browser, it shows bunch of junk characters with a content type of text/plain.

eg: `https://www.domainname.com/client/image-name.jpg` shows as like below

```
    �3�!1AQa"q2‘¡±B#$RÁb34r‚ÑC%’Sðáñcs5¢²ƒ
    &D“TdEÂ£t6ÒUâeò³„ÃÓuãóF'”¤…´•ÄÔäô¥µÅÕåõVfv†–¦¶ÆÖæö
7GWgw‡—§·Ç×ç÷�5�!1AQaq"2‘¡±B#ÁRÑð3$bár‚’CScs4ñ%¢²
ƒ&5ÂÒD“T£dEU6teâò³„ÃÓuãóF”¤…´•ÄÔäô¥µÅÕåõVfv†–¦
¶ÆÖæö'7GWgw‡—§·ÇÿÚ���?�Þé½}ØŸZ:Ãú¦kÛO¨Ë\Æ–Ù]u6šFï~ÍþÚYï
]/MúÅÑº§¨0òCÝKwØ×‡Vàßô›nm£þZäú&o×~¨Üº›{)uö1–
ÍßêW^òÃívÖ=ÿ�Idýd­
```

Please provide advice about what I have missed in my code.

Comment: Have you set the content type for the image? If it shows it as text/plain, you probably haven't specified what content type it is, or have specified it wrong. You did not tell are you site admin or what you mean by "my code".

Comment: Do you have any funny htaccess rewrite on your server?

Comment: As the problem is probably related to server settings, you should describe this server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably did not send the proper header while rendering the image to the browser:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
```

Comment: How do i use this on my code? the same happen for gif and png mage formats.

Comment: That's not a question we can answer unless you show us the code.