# Image with 'image/pjpeg' mime type not displaying via PHP using GD library

Tags: php, image, jpeg

I’m learning PHP & I’m working on a simple upload and display image exercise out of a Apress PHP book. I’m using the latest [Eclipse](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/) program, XAMPP, Apache, etc…

The problem I’m having is that the image being uploaded is a JPEG but it is being read as type PJPEG. It pushes my `IF` statement to the `FALSE` section with my error messages.

If I change the all the criteria to `pjpeg`, then for some reason I get weird raw code instead of a picture.

How do I ensure that my image being loaded stays a jpeg or how can I rewrite my code to upload and output a `pjpeg` and actually display in browser.

UPDATE: the code provided by Jake is working but the image itself is not displaying in browsers. Tested in Chrome, Firefox and IE.

```
<?php 

error_reporting(E_ALL);

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

    if ( isset($_FILES['photo']) && 
        is_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name']) && 
        $_FILES['photo']['error']==UPLOAD_ERR_OK ){

            if ($_FILES['photo']['type'] == 'image/jpeg'){

                $j = imagecreatefromjpeg($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name']);

                header('Content-Type: image/jpeg'); 

                imagejpeg($j);

                imagedestroy($j);

            } else {
                echo "Uploaded file was not a jpeg. <br />";
                echo "The file ", $_FILES['photo']['name'], " uploaded was a ", $_FILES['photo']['type'];
            }
    } else {
        echo "No photo upload"; 
    }
} else {

?>

<form action="test.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label for="photo">User Photo:</label>
    <input type="file" name="photo" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value = "Upload a JPEG" />
</form>

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Show the results of `var_dump($_FILES['photo'])`

Comment: this is what i got

array(5) { ["name"]=> string(10) "sample.jpg" ["type"]=> string(11) "image/pjpeg" ["tmp_name"]=> string(24) "C:\xampp\tmp\php1A4D.tmp" ["error"]=> int(0) ["size"]=> int(7048) }

Comment: I have eclipse setup to use Chrome as my default internal and external browser. i even tested the code in firefox and got the same thing. i read online that there are funky things about pjpeg in internet explorer; i'm advoiding IE until it the basic problem solved. @Jake, THANKS!

Answer (score 2):

Change the code from this:

```
if ($_FILES['photo']['type'] == 'image/jpeg'){
    $j = imagecreatefromjpeg($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name']);
    header('Content-Type: image/jpeg'); 
    imagejpeg($j);
    imagedestroy($j);
}
```

To this:

```
// Set an array of mime types that you accept as valid.
$valid_photo_mime_types = array('image/jpeg', 'image/pjpeg');

// Now check if the mime type of the uploaded file matches your array values of valid photo mime types.
if (in_array($_FILES['photo']['type'], $valid_photo_mime_types)){

    // Now let’s ingest the file that was uploaded & assign it to $j using the GD graphics library.
    $j = imagecreatefromjpeg($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name']);

    // Set the header to be whatever the uploaded file mime-type is.
    header('Content-Type: ' . $_FILES['photo']['type']); 

    // Now send the image to the browser.
    imagejpeg($j);

    // And finally 'destroy' the stored image to free up memory.
    imagedestroy($j);

}
```

Note that I git rid of the double-spacing of lines in your original example for space. And in my rewrite I am setting an array named `$photo_mime_types` and then using [`in_array`](https://www.php.net/in_array) to check if `$_FILES['photo']['type']`matches a value in `$photo_mime_types`.  Then for `header('Content-Type: '…` I am setting that to whatever the value of `$_FILES['photo']['type']` since at that point that value is valid, correct? Well programming is about avoiding repetition so let’s just pass what is valid when we know it is valid.

**EDIT:** This still seems to not be working for the original poster, so another debugging idea is to check the headers sent via `curl -I` from the command line. Unsure if you can do this on Windows, but if not you should figure out how to since `curl` is a great debugging tool for things like this.  On a Mac OS X machine or a Unix/Linux box just run this command. For example, a call to the image logo on Google right now:

```
curl -I https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png
```

The output I get is as follows:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: image/png
Content-Length: 14022
Last-Modified: Wed, 09 Oct 2013 01:35:39 GMT
Date: Thu, 15 May 2014 01:47:25 GMT
Expires: Thu, 15 May 2014 01:47:25 GMT
Cache-Control: private, max-age=31536000
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Server: sffe
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Alternate-Protocol: 443:quic
```

Those are all of the headers that are sent with that image that tells the browser what to do with the image. Note the `Content-Type: image/png`.  Now just substitute the URL to your local PHP code instead of the Google URL & check the output. Also look at [this answer on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12294070/image-showing-as-junk-characters-in-the-browser). As well [as this one that explains how to use `getimagesize`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2006632/php-how-can-i-check-if-a-file-is-mp3-or-image-file?rq=1) to get data about the image within your PHP code. [`getimagesize`](http://www.php.net/getimagesize) is useful as well to show you what PHP is seeing the data to be.

Comment: I used your code and I understand how it works. the problem is that the output to my browser is a bunch of raw code (no image to display). is that normal in PHP?

Answer (score 0):

change

```
if ($_FILES['photo']['type'] == 'image/jpeg'){
```

to

```
if (preg_match('@^image/[a-z\-]jpeg@',$_FILES['photo']['type']) === true) {
```

this will match any type starting with 'image/' and ending with 'jpeg' and containing only lowercase letter and - characters

Comment: an elaboration of the regex and what you've changed would be good if our peer is a beginner