# Displaying PNG file from PHP

Tags: php, image, png

I'm using a PHP library to display a small png image. It works fine placed into its own PHP file, right here: https://www.sidesay.co/test_draw.php

The code is quite simple.

```
<?php

    require './libraries/Sparkline-master/autoload.php';
    
    $sparkline = new Davaxi\Sparkline();
    $sparkline->setData(array(2,4,5,6,10,7,8,5,7,7,11,8,6,9,11,9,13,14,12,16));
    $sparkline->display();
    
?>
```

But when I include the above code into my larger php file for displaying with the rest of the webpage, I get junk data where the image should be, that looks like this:

> �PNG  IHDRPغ�
> pHYs���+�IDATX��OLZw�?���4H�@\’j�DOzX�d��SM��,f.��%���Poۚ�^l�fa�lz/�^�ɥä�9�AuB��C�{(�oP�):u�����}�߇���C�(��e18��q��Rĥ̡�
> �D�n1A�9��R�2�C)��I��ID9�A_���L_�A�//

etc.

Any ideas?

---

EDIT: I've created a quick PHP file to show the problem. Including a Header does not resolve the problem. It only works without HTML or if I place the PHP at the top it works but my HTML will not display at all.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>TEST</title>
</head>

<?php

    header('Content-type: image/png');
    require './libraries/Sparkline-master/autoload.php';
    
    $sparkline = new Davaxi\Sparkline();
    $sparkline->setData(array(2,4,5,6,10,7,8,5,7,7,11,8,6,9,11,9,13,14,12,16));
    $sparkline->display();

?>


<body>
    <br>
    <p>Not displaying</p>
</body>
</html>
```

The output to this can be seen here:

https://www.sidesay.co/error_draw.php

I have also tried using the imagepng function but the junk data persists.

```
imagepng($sparkline->display());
```

Comment: [Hope it will help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12294070/image-showing-as-junk-characters-in-the-browser)

Comment: You want to display the image in the HTML document ?

Comment: yes. You can't generate the image and create the html in the same file can you? That's what I'm starting to conclude.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot display any html in this file.

But, to display the PNG, you have to add this:

```php
<?php
    header('Content-Type: image/png');
?>
```

Adding this will make the browser display only an image:
[image]

Comment: So the answer is that a generated image can't be created as part of a html file? How do I call it into a webpage? I somehow save it, then call it separately, then destroy it?

Comment: I am unable to understand you.

Comment: I would like to include the image into my html. I can create the image using the function sparkline() but how do I output that image with additional HTML around it in real time?

Comment: I'm sorry but you can't add both the image and html in the same file. The most ideal solution is to create the image, save it to a file and then display it using the <img> tag in html.

Comment: If I could help you, could you upvote my answer? Actually I am new to this community. :)

Answer (score 0):

Import all the image related code into an my_image.php file and write that file in the src="" attribute of the  tag.

```
<?php
    /*this is my_image.php*/
    header('Content-Type: image/png');
    require './libraries/Sparkline-master/autoload.php';
    
    $sparkline = new Davaxi\Sparkline();
    $sparkline->setData(array(2,4,5,6,10,7,8,5,7,7,11,8,6,9,11,9,13,14,12,16));
    $sparkline->display();
?>
```

now use this like a image file

```
/*this is index.html*/
<html>
<head>
    <title>TEST</title>
</head>
<body>

     <img src="your_path/my_image.php"/>
    <br>
    <p>Not displaying</p>
</body>
</html>
```